# Checking for defined variables in makefile macros

Tags: makefile, macros, gnu-make

I'm having some trouble getting a GNU Makefile macro to work the way I would like it to. Here's my test:

```
TEST1 = defined
#TEST2 = defined

define add_ext
ifndef $(1)
    $(error $(1) not defined)
endif

$(1)_EXT = $(1).extended
endef

TESTS = TEST1 TESTS2

$(foreach test,$(TESTS),$(eval $(call add_ext,$(test))))

all:
    @echo TEST1: $(TEST1), $(TEST1_EXT)
    @echo TEST2: $(TEST2), $(TEST2_EXT)
```

The macro is supposed to accept the name of a variable and the macro first checks that it is already defined, then creates an associated variable.

Given that I have commented out `TEST2`, I was expecting this to fail on `TEST2`. But this is the error message:

```
Makefile:15: *** TEST1 not defined.  Stop.
```

This is very similar to what Buildroot does in their Makefiles:
https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/tree/package/pkg-generic.mk#n409

Anyone know where my trouble is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape make-functions within the macro definition, i.e.

```
define add_ext
ifndef $(1)
$$(error $(1) not defined)
endif

$(1)_EXT = $(1).extended
endef
```

Also, in your:

```
ifndef $(1)
    $(error $(1) not defined)
endif
```

I can't tell whether `$(error ...)` is indented by tab or spaces, but it
must not be tab-indented, so best not indent at all.

Comment: Aw shoot, it would have to be something that simple. Thanks!